# QGIS 3.4 merge raster output only 1 px wide

Tags: qgis, raster, merge, qgis-3

I have four .xyz files with terrain data. I can convert them to TIFs in QGIS 3.4, but in either format, merging them fails. The merge output always has the X dimension of the merged rasters, but a Y dimension of only one pixel.
This happens in QGIS 2.18, 3.2 and 3.4 and whatever settings I apply. Any idea how to solve this problem?

The input rasters look like this:
[image: input rasters]

The output looks like this:
[image: output]

Comment: Does this happens with the merge tools or virtual raster catalog? Are they the sametyp of file (geotif, for instance)

Comment: Yes, all files are of the same type. I tried it with geoTIF and with .XYZ. It happens with the merge tool.

Comment: Have you tried to build a Virtual Raster with the 4 rasters and then, export it into a new file ?

Comment: Additional details: Horizontal merge does work (for me), but vertical doesn't. Trying to build a virtual raster throws "gdalbuildvrt does not support positive NS resolution". Also SAGA "add raster values to points" fails.

Comment: Forget about the SAGA-part, that was due to special symbols in the file paths.

Comment: Sample data would be quite helpful.

Comment: @Saijin_Naib https://data.geobasis-bb.de/geobasis/daten/dgm/xyz/ - any four tiles which form a square should suffice

Comment: @Erik, thank you so much.

Comment: did you know that this data from brandenburg is also available as a wcs?

Answer (score 4):

(using QGIS 3.8.2)

I was able to merge 4 adjacent tiles from the link provided in the comment from @Erik using:

- **Warp** (gdalwarp), in the QGIS toolbox, outputting them to **.tif**
- **Merge** (gdal_merge), in the toolbox again.

I didn't have to change any settings, I left everything as default.

[image]

Comment: This is the same procedure as I used the first time. I just retried it - and it did work. What the heck?

Comment: @Erik Weird. I did try to built a VRT and it gave me the same NS values error, so it should be the same file structure.

Comment: Well, though technically you didn't solve the original problem, your answer shows how to do it correctly - and encouraged me to try again. So, while I can't mark you answer as correct, I can grant you the title "bountyhunter" =)

Comment: Well that was unexpected! I was sure someone would come in and point out the bug report that was at the bottom of this.

Answer (score 3):

Your images have a positive N-S pixel resolution in the geotransform. This is 
quite unusual and means the origin coordinates for the image are in the 
lower-left rather than the upper-left of the image. In the usual upper-left 
case the geotransform N-S pixel resolution would be negative.

Are you sure your image georeferences are correct?

Try exporting all your raster as asciis and check the UL or LL settings for irregularities with your favourite text viewer.

Comment: The images are georeferenced correctly (I checked with the basemap).

Answer (score 3):

this is not an answer to your question, but may solve your problem anyways. the rasters that you are trying to mosaic are also available as a WCS under this link: https://isk.geobasis-bb.de/ows/dgm_wcs
You can just add the WCS to QGIS and use it for your processing.

Answer (score 1):

You may try and convert those tiles to a virtual raster. Export this virtual raster then into a new .xyz file and you should be good!

Comment: Trying to build a virtual raster throws "gdalbuildvrt does not support positive NS resolution".

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the issue (again) with the same data source.

Solved the issue by transforming the data to the same CRS, but with half the ground resolution (2m instead of 1m). Then merging worked.