# DGM1, virtual raster error

Tags: qgis, dem, error, tiles, virtual-raster

I want to create a virtual raster with DEM1, existing of 133 tiles (QGIS 3.18.3). It show following processing warning:

GDAL command:

```
gdalbuildvrt -resolution average -separate -r nearest -input_file_list C:/Users/v.dosky/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_1eb4cddcda444e0d8d1834f5567da2b6/59fdb7c3769b4883ae765e00a787f3dc/buildvrtInputFiles.txt "//fileserver/freigabe/02_Projekte"
```

GDAL command output:

```
Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support positive NS resolution. Skipping //fileserver/freigabe/02_Projekte/DGM1_Kacheln_DTMBIN1UTM_406000_5296000_dtm.xyz
Warning 6: gdalbuildvrt does not support positive NS resolution. Skipping //fileserver/freigabe/02_ProjekteBearbeitung/02_GIS/02_Rohdaten/DGM1_Kacheln_DTMBIN1UTM_406000_5296000_dtm.xyz
```

and following Python error:

```
2021-09-15T10:38:31     WARNING    warning:C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\status_codes.py:18: DeprecationWarning: invalid escape sequence \o
 
 traceback: File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 354, in startPlugin
  if not _startPlugin(packageName):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 334, in _startPlugin
  plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\__init__.py", line 29, in classFactory
  from MetaSearch.plugin import MetaSearchPlugin
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\plugin.py", line 34, in 
  from MetaSearch.dialogs.maindialog import MetaSearchDialog
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\dialogs\maindialog.py", line 50, in 
  from owslib.csw import CatalogueServiceWeb # spellok
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\owslib\csw.py", line 27, in 
  from owslib.util import OrderedDict
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\owslib\util.py", line 32, in 
  import requests
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 114, in 
  from .models import Request, Response, PreparedRequest
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 43, in 
  from .status_codes import codes
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 724, in exec_module
  File "", line 860, in get_code
  File "", line 791, in source_to_code
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
 
2021-09-15T10:38:31     WARNING    warning:C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py:737: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated, and in 3.8 it will stop working
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
 
 traceback: File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 354, in startPlugin
  if not _startPlugin(packageName):
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 334, in _startPlugin
  plugins[packageName] = package.classFactory(iface)
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\__init__.py", line 29, in classFactory
  from MetaSearch.plugin import MetaSearchPlugin
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\plugin.py", line 34, in 
  from MetaSearch.dialogs.maindialog import MetaSearchDialog
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\dialogs\maindialog.py", line 56, in 
  from MetaSearch.dialogs.manageconnectionsdialog import ManageConnectionsDialog
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\dialogs\manageconnectionsdialog.py", line 35, in 
  from MetaSearch.util import (get_connections_from_file, get_ui_class,
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\MetaSearch\util.py", line 35, in 
  from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in 
  from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 15, in 
  from jinja2 import nodes
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 1035, in _handle_fromlist
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\nodes.py", line 19, in 
  from jinja2.utils import Markup
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "", line 728, in exec_module
  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\jinja2\utils.py", line 485, in 
  from collections import MutableMapping
  File "C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS3~1.8/apps/qgis/./python\qgis\utils.py", line 737, in _import
  mod = _builtin_import(name, globals, locals, fromlist, level)
  File "", line 1032, in _handle_fromlist
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.8\apps\Python37\lib\collections\__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
  DeprecationWarning, stacklevel=2)*
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QGIS 3.4 merge raster output only 1 px wide](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/310450/qgis-3-4-merge-raster-output-only-1-px-wide)

Comment: Error seems to tell that in your xyz files the lines advance from south to north and gdalbuildvrtr does not support that. But a mosaic of 133 xyz files will probably be very slow anyway. I suggest to convert the files into GeoTIFFs and use them in VRT. And I guess that you do not really want to get a result with 133 bands as you get with the -separate option.